# Calling jQuery function on external page from html.actionlink

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I have an action link like this:

```
@html.actionlink("link", "action", "controller", new { id = item.id }
```

I want this link to call a jQuery function on an external page. I have tried with `onclick` but it always goes to the default controller action method and so does for `@class`.

I would like to know can I use it like this:

```
@html.actionlink("link text", null, null, new { id = item.id }, new { onclick = "myfunction() }
```

This still does not call the jQuery function, what am I doing wrong?

here  is my html hyperlink

@item.ProductID.ToString()

and below is my jquery script locate in an external js file

```
$(document).ready({
function showdetails(id)
{
alert("you clicked me")
});
```

Comment: If you just want to make it run a jQuery function and not go to a controller then there's no point using the actionLink helper - the whole purpose of that is to generate a hyperlink with the correct URL to the action method. Instead, just write a HTML link (or button) directly and attach the click event to it. There's no need to us any Razor code.

Comment: Nobody has an idea

Comment: What do you mean? My comment above already tells you exactly what you need to do. Is there something you didn't understand in what I wrote? If so please mention it.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I did not see it. would you please show me an example, I am totally confused because I want to pass the item.itemID to the jquery function

Comment: I mean just make your own link or button using HTML directly. e.g. `<button type="button" onclick="myfunction()">Click here</button>`. Like I said, you don't need Razor code, if you just want to run some Javascript.

Comment: it is a text that is contain in a table it cannot be a button. I tried this <a href="#" onclick="myfunction()">link text/<a> but how to pass the id

Comment: If it's part of a web page then it can be a button. Or you can use a hyperlink. Or you can use a button but have some CSS which makes looks like a link. It doesn't matter.

Comment: Your original example doesn't pass any ID to the JavaScript function. Are you now saying you need to send a value?

Comment: Yes, I also need to send the item id to the jQuery function

Comment: Well you can inject server-side values into the JS quite easily, e.g. something like `<a href="#" onclick="myfunction(@item.id)">link text/<a>`

Comment: I did the link just like that and the jquery like function myfunction(id){} not being it when link is clicked

Comment: Any errors in your browser's Console? Also bear in mind that clicking a hyperlink can cause your page to be refreshed. That is one reason I recommended using a button instead. Remember you can use CSS to make your button look like a link, if that's important to you. So maybe something like `<button type="button" class="linkbutton" onclick="myfunction(@item.id)">Click here</button>`. And then set properties of the linkbutton class in CSS. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/bd3c8k6u/

Comment: Ok I thought about your recommendation of using a button, but let me explain better. I got that from a database which are displayed in table, one of the column is the itemid when the item that i turn into a hyperlink so it can give more details about the item. Now if an error saying the name of the function is not defined.

Comment: "one of the column is the itemid when the item that i turn into a hyperlink so it can give more details about the item" ...none of this stops you from swapping the hyperlink for a button. Try my demo, you can't even see the difference when it's rendered.

Comment: "the name of the function is not defined"...so, where in your view did you place the `<script>` block containing this function? It should be defined somewhere before the table.

Comment: The function is in an external js file. Note that all other function on the page works normalyl except for the one. I dunno if it is something with the way I define the function. which is  function functionanme(param){ code to be executed)}

Comment: ok well have you included that JS file in your view via a `<script` tag? If so, did you check that it loaded correctly?

Comment: Yes it is included and loaded correctly for all other function on that file work normally

Comment: Ok. That's pretty strange then. Hard to help you further without actually seeing the code.

Comment: How would you write a function in an external js file.... I can show you the code just dunno how to post them. How would you call that function from an a tag

Comment: You write it the same way you write a function anywhere. There's no difference just because it's stored in another file. See my JSFiddle demo above - that shows you how you'd define the `myfunction` function you talked about. Whether that's in another file or directly coded into the HTML page makes no difference, as long as the file is loaded via a script tag, at some point before the function is called.

Comment: _"dunno how to post them"_ ...use the "edit" button under your question to update your post, then you can paste any relevant code into it.

Comment: I just post the code

Comment: Ok the mistake is to put the function within a `$(document).ready({` block. It's unnecessary because the idea of that block is only to stop code executing before the page has finished loading. With a function, which is only called from other code, not executed immediately, you don't have that worry. And it causes the error because it means that your function only has scope within that block. It isn't accessible to code outside the block.

Comment: Everything works fine now. Thank you so so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to make it run a jQuery function and not go to a controller then there's no point using the actionLink helper - the whole purpose of that is to generate a hyperlink with the correct URL to the action method. Instead, just write a HTML link (or button) directly and attach the click event to it. There's no need to us any Razor code.

Something like this:

```
<button type="button" class="linkbutton" onclick="myfunction(@item.id)">Click here</button>
```

The other mistake is to put the function within a `$(document).ready({` block. It's unnecessary because the idea of that block is only to stop code executing before the page has finished loading. With a function, which is only called from other code, not executed immediately, you don't have that worry. And it causes the error because it means that your function only has scope within that block. It isn't accessible to code outside the block.

Demo:

```js
function myfunction(x)
{
  alert(x);
}
```

```css
.linkbutton
{
  border: none;
  background: none;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration:underline;
}

.linkbutton:hover
{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="linkbutton" onclick="myfunction(3)">Click here</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, with your help everything works fine even though I have another problem with jQuery I will ask a new question. I hope you will be able to help me out... Thank you so much. and please tell how to follow you on this site.

Comment: You can't "follow" me as such, i.e. you can't get notifications for things I do. It's not social media. You can follow topic tags instead to see interesting questions. But can see my profile at https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson and see what answers I've given etc.